# Fitting data into a Quintic.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Good morning.  I have the following information regarding a quintic function.  I'm trying to use linear algebra to solve with the given information.  I know the general quintic is

$$p(x)=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f$$

and thus it's derivative is

$$p'(x)=5ax^4+4bx^3+3cx^2+2dx+e$$

With those two polynomials, i know the following

$$p(0)=4, p(1)=5, p(3)=2, p(4.5)=3, p(6)=0.5, p(8)=6$$

and

$$p'(1)=p'(3)=p'(4.5)=p'(6)=0$$

Now since $p(0)=4,$ then $f=4$.  So at least that is known.  Then I set up a $9\times6$ coefficient matrix with all thise conditions by substituting known $x$ values into $p$ and $p'$ and row reduced it and i keep getting either 'no solution' or I get a similar shaped polynomial that almost fits, but won't satisfy the initial condition I have here.  The matrix is really hard to type in here, but I think this would be the method...

Is this the correct way to finish this problem?  Should I be row reducing a matrix of coefficients that satisfies these initial conditions?  Or am I missing a step or two?

The other method was to work backwards from the zeros. Since we know the zeroes of the derivative, we can say that

$$p'(x)=k(x-1)(x-3)(x-4.5)(x-6)$$

up to some scalar $k$.  So I can expand to

$$p'(x)=k(x^4-14.5x^3+72x^2-139.5x+81)$$

and integrating gives

$$p(x)=k(0.2x^5-3.625x^4+24x^3-69.75x^2+81x+C))=k(0.2x^5-3.625x^4+24x^3-69.75x^2+81x)+4$$

Evaluating at $x=1$ gives

$$p(1)=k(0.2-3.625+24-69.75+81)=1$$
$$k=\frac{40}{1273}$$

Unfortunately, this doesn't work either as when I try and evaluate $p(3)$, i get $4.57$

So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think there is such a polynomial? (There is not.) In general, given $n+1$ distinct $x$-values, there is a unique interpolating polynomial of degree $n$. That is, your first six conditions already determine $p$ uniquely. It would be pure luck if it also satisfied four more conditions on the derivative.

Comment: So would that mean that I could try fitting a octic polynomial since I have 9 initial conditions?

Comment: I count 10 conditions, so you would need a polynomial of degree 9 (a nonic one?).

Comment: Ah yes, you are right...  nonic.  Funny name.  I will try that.